# Error to create a trigger for insert data

Tags: sql-server, database-trigger

I have a problem when create a trigger to insert data.
i have 2 computers and i wanna write a website to everybody order and rent it by time.
But I have trouble writing the rental function to insert data into the order table.
If the computer has an id = 1 ordered at 7:00 am-9:00am, 12:00 to 14:00
So how do I prevent users from being able to put it at that time or in the past with a trigger

I try to write a trigger but it not working

```
==========================Booking====================
id_booking  |id_user    |total_price    |status_booking |id_cpt |start_time                 |end_time   |time_create
3             1              NULL               NULL        22   1998-01-01 01:00:00.000  1998-01-01 03:00:00.000            NULL
4             1              NULL               NULL        22   1998-01-01 05:00:00.000  1998-01-01 07:00:00.000            NULL
5             2              NULL               NULL        23   1998-01-01 07:00:00.000  1998-01-01 09:00:00.000            NULL
========================================================


======================Computers==========================
id_cpt  code_computer   id_status_cpt   id_room
22          VIP01                  1    1
23          VIP02                  1    1
=========================================================
```

**My Trigger**

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
CREATE TRIGGER beginInsert
ON  booking
for insert
AS 
BEGIN
--BEGIN DECALRE---
declare @id_user int
declare @total_price int
declare @status_booking int
declare @id_cpt int
declare @start_time datetime
declare @end_time datetime
declare @time_create datetime 
declare @start_time_oder datetime
declare @end_time_order datetime


declare @check_time bit
--END DECALRE---

--SET VALUE OF VARIABLE---

select @id_cpt=id_cpt, @start_time_oder=@start_time_oder, @end_time_order=@end_time_order, @status_booking=0, @check_time=0
from inserted

--GET TIME IN BOOKING TO CHECK--

select @start_time=booking.start_time, @end_time=booking.end_time from booking

--END GET TIME IN BOOKING TO CHECK--

--SET VALUE OF VARIABLE---



if (@start_time_oder <@end_time_order)

    begin
        print(@start_time)
        print(@start_time_oder)
        if (@start_time_oder < @start_time and @end_time_order <@start_time) or (@start_time_oder > @end_time and @end_time_order >@end_time)

            begin

                insert into booking values(@id_user, @total_price, @status_booking,@id_cpt,@start_time_oder, @end_time_order, @time_create)

            end

        else

                rollback transaction
    end
else
    rollback transaction
```

END
GO

Expect result:
when user select a computer id=22, and order it, user cant order this computer since 1998-01-01 01:00:00.000 to  1998-01-01 03:00:00.000 and 1998-01-01 05:00:00.000 to  1998-01-01 07:00:00.000

Tks so much!!!

Comment: and intercept user cant order at time in the past

Comment: You said you wrote a trigger but you haven't included it. Can you please share your attempt(s) and explain why they didn't work. Otherwise it's impossible for us to tell you what the problem is. Thanks.

Comment: so sorry, i added my trigger code, tks so much!

Comment: Why is this not a check constraint? You're not using the inserted virtual table and you're doing a second insert on the table.

Comment: The trigger has a major flaw here, it assumes that only one row will be inserted. A triggers fires once per DML statement, not once per row. But @LuisCazares is right, this should be a `CHECK CONSTRAINT`, not a trigger.